# Why is the audio gone from a video I uploaded to Youtube?

Tags: youtube

I just made a video with Windows Movie Maker, and uploaded to Youtube, only to find the audio track totally missing. Is it because I chose a popular song as the audio track (DRM/licensing issues) ?

Comment: As far as I know, your video gets banned if you use unlicensed audio.

Comment: In fact, does this qusetion belong on Webapps?

Comment: @Michael - see also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/suggestions-for-online-video-service-that-doesnt-filter-unlicensed-audio-tracks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely yes. You can find out yourself by visiting the list of our videos "My Uploaded Videos" on youtube (you need to be logged in) and see if there is a Note about "Matched third party content".

Comment: Yeap, there it is.

Comment: In fact, I got an email from Youtube about it, I just hadn't had a chance to check my mail yet :)

Comment: Hmm, I think I just upvoted this answer twice - once on Superuser, and once here.